# Simpler version of Tchebotarev's theorem (base field $\mathbb{Q}$)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

All texts I could find about Tchebotarev theorem prove it for a general Galois extension $L|K$.

I wonder if there is a specific proof for the simpler case of $K=\mathbb{Q}$, i.e.:

> For a given conjugacy class $C$ of $\text{Gal}(L|\mathbb{Q})$, the density of the set of unramified primes $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\text{Frob}_{\mathfrak{P}}\in C$ for all $\mathfrak{P}\mid p$ is equal to $\frac{\#C}{\#\text{Gal}(L|\mathbb{Q})}$.

I imagine the proof should be more elementary, but I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: Look at the Galois closure $F/L/K$, Chebotarev theorem for $Gal(F/\Bbb{Q})$ implies Chebotarev theorem for $Gal(F/K)$ thus for $Gal(F/K)/Gal(F/L) = Gal(L/K)$.

Comment: I don't understand. If $F| \mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, $F$ is already the Galois closure... am I missing something?

Comment: Let $L/K$ Galois, $F/Q$ the Galois closure of $L/Q$ and $\rho$ a representation of $Gal(L/K)$, then $Gal(L/K) = Gal(F/K)/Gal(F/L)$ so $\rho$ is a representation of $Gal(F/K)$, and $\pi = Ind_{Gal(F/k)}^{Gal(F/Q)} \rho$ is a representation of $Gal(F/Q)$, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_L-function) up to the few ramified primes $$\exp(\sum_{P^m, P \in O_K} \frac{tr(\rho(Frob_{P,L/K}^m))}{m} N(P)^{-sm}) = L(s,\rho) = L(s,\pi) = \exp(\sum_{p^m, p \in \Bbb{Z}} \frac{tr(\pi(Frob_{p,F/Q}^m))}{m} p^{-sm})$$ Chebotarev is really the PNT for those Artin L-functions.